# Center align multiple layers

Tags: photoshop, center-align

I have a button with 3 layers: Rounded Rectangle for outline, arrow icon and text, like this:

[image]

How do I center align the arrow and text to the rectangle without merging them in one layer? I tried linking them together and then align to selection, but that way they get stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

1. Group the two layers (arrow and text) by selecting those two layers and choosing LAYERS > GROUP LAYERS (`Ctrl` + `G`)
2. select the Layer Group you just created and the rectangle layer and Align center

Comment: To [create a key object to align to](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/49501/3841), `Ctrl`-`click` the layer you want to align to; this will create a selection for that layer's object and the Layer Group will align to the selection you just created.

Answer (score 0):

even I dont know the shortcut. but I have 1 idea.

1. create a rectangle shape is equal width to the text and the icon
2. then align center to the shape
3. then move that text and icon in same position.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin, It would be best to enable smart guides before you start alignment. This displays precise guides when you manually move objects to align with other objects. You can drag each layer separately to align with another object in a different layer.

HTH/B